# Julia macro expansion order

Tags: julia

I would like to write a macro `@unpack t` which takes an object `t` and copies all its fields into local scope. For example, given

```
immutable Foo
    i::Int
    x::Float64
end
foo = Foo(42,pi)
```

the expression `@unpack foo` should expand into

```
i = foo.i
x = foo.x
```

Unfortunately, such a macro cannot exist since it would have to know the type of the passed object. To circumvent this limitation, I introduce a type-specific macro `@unpackFoo foo` with the same effect, but since I'm lazy I want the compiler to write `@unpackFoo` for me. So I change the type definition to

```
@unpackable immutable Foo
    i::Int
    x::Float64
end
```

which should expand into

```
immutable Foo
    i::Int
    x::Float64
end
macro unpackFoo(t)
    return esc(quote
        i = $t.i
        x = $t.x
    end)    
end
```

Writing `@unpackable` is not too hard:

```
macro unpackable(expr)
    if expr.head != :type
        error("@unpackable must be applied on a type definition")
    end

    name = isa(expr.args[2], Expr) ? expr.args[2].args[1] : expr.args[2]
    fields = Symbol[]
    for bodyexpr in expr.args[3].args
        if isa(bodyexpr,Expr) && bodyexpr.head == :(::)
            push!(fields,bodyexpr.args[1])
        elseif isa(bodyexpr,Symbol)
            push!(fields,bodyexpr)
        end
    end

    return esc(quote
        $expr
        macro $(symbol("unpack"*string(name)))(t)
            return esc(Expr(:block, [:($f = $t.$f) for f in $fields]...))
        end
    end)
end
```

In the REPL, this definition works just fine:

```
julia> @unpackable immutable Foo
           i::Int
           x::Float64
       end

julia> macroexpand(:(@unpackFoo foo))
quote 
    i = foo.i
    x = foo.x
end
```

Problems arise if I put the `@unpackFoo` in the same compilation unit as the `@unpackable`:

```
julia> @eval begin
       @unpackable immutable Foo
           i::Int
           x::Float64
       end
       foo = Foo(42,pi)
       @unpackFoo foo
       end
ERROR: UndefVarError: @unpackFoo not defined
```

I assume the problem is that the compiler tries to proceed as follows

1. Expand `@unpackable` but do not parse it.
2. Try to expand `@unpackFoo` which fails because the expansion of `@unpackable` has not been parsed yet.
3. If we wouldn't fail already at step 2, the compiler would now parse the expansion of `@unpackable`.

This circumstance prevents `@unpackable` from being used in a source file. Is there any way of telling the compiler to swap steps 2. and 3. in the above list?

---

The background to this question is that I'm working on an iterator-based implementation of iterative solvers in the spirit of https://gist.github.com/jiahao/9240888. Algorithms like MinRes require quite a number of variables in the corresponding state object (8 currently), and I neither want to write `state.variable` every time I use a variable in e.g. the `next()` function, nor do I want to copy all of them manually as this bloats up the code and is hard to maintain. In the end, this is mainly an exercise in meta-programming though.

Comment: I think you can do this much more simply using generated functions. But what is the use case?

Comment: I don't think generated functions will work since functions introduce a new variable scope and can only operate within that scope. I'll add some remarks about the background to the question.

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it it would probably be more reasonable in my use case to put away with the state type and use tuples instead, for which I can get the `@unpack` behaviour by tuple unpacking (i.e. `i,x = (42,pi)`).

Comment: @gTcV Unpacking in Julia is done by the iteration protocol, so you can attain similar behaviour by implementing `start`, `next`, and `done`. See http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/interfaces/

Comment: An example of how to unpack a custom type is given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38289726/julia-custom-type-assignment/38290263?noredirect=1#comment63999270_38290263

Comment: Try having a look at `Parameters` package. It has an `@unpack` macro and the accompanying machinery similar to what you suggest you need.

Comment: @DanGetz That's indeed precisely what I was looking for! If you turn your comment into an answer it might be easier for others to find, and I can upvote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would suggest writing this as:

```
immutable Foo
  ...
end

unpackable(Foo)
```

where `unpackable` is a function which takes the type, constructs the appropriate expression and `eval`s it. There are a couple of advantages to this, e.g. that you can apply it to any type without it being fixed at definition time, and the fact that you don't have to do a bunch of parsing of the type declaration (you can just call `fieldnames(Foo) == [:f, :i]` and work with that).

Secondly, while I don't know your use case in detail (and dislike blanket rules) I will warn that this kind of thing is frowned upon. It makes code harder to read because it introduces a non-local dependency; suddenly, in order to know whether `x` is a local or global variable, you have to look up the definition of a type in a whole different file. A better, and more general, approach is to explicitly unpack variables, and this is available in MacroTools.jl via the `@destruct` macro:

```
@destruct _.(x, i) = myfoo
# now we can use x and i
```

(You can destruct nested data structures and indexable objects too, which is nice.)

To answer your question: you're essentially right about how Julia runs code (s/parse/evaluate). The whole block is parsed, expanded and evaluated together, which means in your example you're trying to expand `@unpackFoo` before it's been defined.

*However*, when loading a .jl file, Julia evaluates blocks in the file one at a time, rather than all at once.

This means that you can happily write a file like this:

```
macro foo()
  :(println("hi"))
end

@foo()
```

and run `julia foo.jl` or `include("foo.jl")` and it will run fine. You just can't have a macro definition and its use in the same block, as in your `begin` block above.

Answer (score 1):

Try having a look at `Parameters` package by Mauro (https://github.com/mauro3/Parameters.jl). It has an `@unpack` macro and the accompanying machinery similar to what you suggest you need.